# Open text file and seperate the lines in Windows Command Line

Tags: cmd

I have a file named test.txt that contain's words.

```
WORD1
WORD2
WORD3
```

And I want to open it and execute some commands. For example;

```
test.exe "WORD1"
test.exe "WORD2"
test.exe "WORD3"
```

I can open the file TYPE test.txt |MORE but I don't know how to seperate them line by line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do test.exe "%%a"
```

If you are running from the prompt rather than within a batch file, use `%` in place of `%%`.